# Paypal donate in MS Office

Tags: excel, paypal

Hello I would like to know how to set direct link from Excel into paypal donate website.
Because it always redirect me with session, and these are temporary, right? 
[Error#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScEIA.png)

PayPal offers some additional software, but this is the wall for donors.
I've watched some threads, but nothing useable.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to setup a direct Paypal button link in MS-Excel. As you
mentioned it is always associated with the session and once you click the link, you will get session related error `sorry your last action could not be completed`. Ms-word/Ms-Excel does not work. Only **PDF** works.